# Objective-C save and load files

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, load, save

Hello I am trying to load data from a file

This function save the data to a file in documents folder

```
- (IBAction)saveUser:(id)sender{
   NSString *name = [nameField stringValue];
   NSString *weight = [weightField stringValue];
   NSDate *date = [datePick dateValue];

   NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
   NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

   NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
   [dict setValue:[nameField stringValue] forKey:@"name"];
   [dict setValue:[weightField stringValue] forKey:@"weight"];
   [dict setValue:date forKey:@"date"];
   [dict writeToFile:name atomically:YES];
}
```

However when I try to load the file and get the data from it I cant, could someone tell me how this is done done.

---

Edit to show loadFunction

```
-(IBAction)loadUser:(id)sender{
 NSString *weight = [weightField stringValue];
 NSDate *date = [datePick dateValue];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *loadPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:name];

NSMutableDictionary *savedData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: name]; 
 NSLog(@"%@", weight);
}
```

Comment: the file does get created but in I dont know how to find the file in objective c and read in data from it

Comment: You've shown us only the half of the code, though.  Can you show us the code you are using to read the data from the file?

Comment: In `loadUser` what is `name`?  You defined `name` in the local context of `saveUser` but I don't see it defined in `loadUser`...

Answer (score 4):

To fix your answer. here is a code that works, you pretty much did not give a filename.

```
NSString *filename = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file.txt"];
```

And in your line where you write the file :

```
[dict writeToFile:name atomically:YES];
```

you must change name to filename, like this

```
[dict writeToFile:filename atomically:YES];
```

And in your load data method :

```
NSString *filename = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file.txt"];

NSMutableDictionary *savedData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filename]; 

NSLog(@"The weight is : %@", [savedData valueForKey:@"weight"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The following seems to do what you intend (minus the UI element dependencies in your code):

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

static NSString *pathToDocuments(void) {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    return [paths objectAtIndex:0];
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool *p = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [dict setValue:@"SomeName" forKey:@"name"];
    [dict setValue:@"SomeWeight" forKey:@"weight"];
    [dict setValue:[NSDate date] forKey:@"date"];

    NSString *filePath = [pathToDocuments() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[dict objectForKey:@"name"]];
    [dict writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

    [dict release];  dict = nil;

    NSLog(@"%s - Confirming dict is nil: %@",__FUNCTION__,dict);

    dict = [[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filePath] mutableCopy];
    NSLog(@"%s - weight = %@",__FUNCTION__,[dict objectForKey:@"weight"] );

    [p release];
}
```

This prints the following to the console:

```
2012-10-19 06:40:38.691 Untitled[10633:707] main - Confirming dict is nil: (null)
2012-10-19 06:40:38.693 Untitled[10633:707] main - weight = SomeWeight
```

**EDIT:**

That said, I think the problem may be the file path in `loadUser`...